# cURL: SSL connect error while trying to install kubectl on RHEL 7

Tags: ssl, curl

I am following Kubernetes documentation to [Install kubectl on Linux](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux) on my RHEL 7 server but I see an

> curl: (35) SSL connect error

error while running the following command:

```
curl -kLO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.7.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl
```

Any pointers to fix this issue will be very helpful for me to move forward.

Comment: Since your issue seems to be related to `curl` and SSL only, can you provide the output of `curl -v "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/"` as code block and by adding your question?

Comment: I am not able to curl to the following URL `https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/` and I should have mentioned that in my previous message, my bad. It is returning `SSL connect error `. So where can I find the correct url to download `kubectl`?

Comment: To be able to help you in this case, can you edit your question and attach the full output of curl -v as code block? It will contain some more information than only the error number.

Comment: `-bash-4.1$ curl -v https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/
* About to connect() to storage.googleapis.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 172.217.167.144... connected
* Connected to storage.googleapis.com (172.217.167.144) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5961
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error`

Comment: @U880D in the above comment I added the output of the curl command that I am getting for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked it and it appeared that the `https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.7.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl` doesn't exist . It looks like it is needed to add ".exe" at the end of the URL.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>
No such object: kubernetes-release/release/v1.7.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl
</Details>
</Error>
```

The official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux) on how to install kubectl on Linux asks to download the latest release _for_linux_ with the following command:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl


curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 44.5M  100 44.5M    0     0  15.8M      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 15.8M
```

Additionally with the URL you have provided you are trying to download `kubectl` for **windows** on RHEL... (/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl in your url)

So, it is merely needed to add .exe in the end of kubectl if you need downloading it for Windows or replace windows with linux in URL :)

Comment: Hi itsh, if the answer helped you it is better to accept the answer as specified in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers